# I need some helping with a currency program

Tags: c++

```css
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

 int quarters;
 int dimes = (quarters * 5);
 int pennies = (quarters * 25);
 int nickles = (pennies / 10);

 cout << "Please enter the amount of quarters you wish to convert" << endl;
 cin >> quarters;

 cout << "Pennies = " << pennies << endl;
 cout << "Dimes = " << dimes << endl;
 cout << "Nickles = " << nickles << endl;
 cin.get();
 cin.get();

 return 0;
}
```

For some reason I keep getting a C4700 error saying quarters is an uninitialized local variable, however if quarters is what is being cined what am I supposed to do? I tried putting in int quarters = 0, however that messed up the program's calculations. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to input the value **before** using it in calculations.

Answer (score 1):

The error message clearly says what's wrong. You have declared `quarters` but haven't initialized before you used it.
Put this

```
cout << "Please enter the amount of quarters you wish to convert" << endl;
cin >> quarters;
```

Before

```
int dimes = (quarters * 5);
int pennies = (quarters * 25);
int nickles = (pennies / 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialise the variable `quarters` and then use it in your calculations.

```
int quarters;
cout<<"Please enter the amount of quarters you wish to convert" << endl;
cin>>quarters;

int dimes = (quarters * 5);
int pennies = (quarters * 25);
int nickles = (pennies / 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int main()
{

    int quarters;
    int dimes;
    int pennies;
    int nickles;

    cout << "Please enter the amount of quarters you wish to convert" << endl;
    cin >> quarters;

    dimes = (quarters * 5);
    pennies = (quarters * 25);
    nickles = (pennies / 10);

    cout << "Pennies = " << pennies << endl;
    cout << "Dimes = " << dimes << endl;
    cout << "Nickles = " << nickles << endl;
    cin.get();
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're happy please accept as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you must get the input before you use it, like:

```
int quarters;
cout << "Please enter the amount of quarters you wish to convert" << endl;
cin >> quarters;
```

and then, AFTER this, you can calculate the other values:

```
int dimes = (quarters * 5);
int pennies = (quarters * 25);
int nickles = (pennies / 10);
```

That said, let's see why it happens. Maybe you think that when you assign a "formula" to a variable (like `dimes = quarters * 5`), the value will always be recalculated, similarly to what Excel does. C++ doesn't work like that: **when you assign a value to a variable you are not defining a general formula which will be automatically updated, but rather calculating the result at that moment.** And the program is run from the top to the bottom. So when you reach the lines that define `dimes`, `pennies` and `nickles`, you are taking the (not defined yet) value of `quarters` and trying to use that to calculate the other variables. Here the program stops, but if it continued and it reached the line with `cin`, it would indeed store the value in `quarters`, but the other 3 variables wouldn't be updated!

Comment: Ah, thank you for the explanation. This will come in handy in  the future in my C++ class. :)